# Shall I hard code the content when using react to build a informative company website?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

We are trying to revamp the company website, and we have some discussion on choosing the technologies. React is one of our options.

However, the website is basically some static contents, which is hardcoded html pages with many different layouts. The contents are static and will never or seldom update. So our idea is to hard code every content into react, there is no API call to get extra contents for most of the cases (except few pages which will load the price table and news from our CMS).

I want to ask react experts for such scenario is it good to use react? Is it a common practice?

Comment: Sounds like a CMS would be more appropriate in your situation (serving multiple static pages that don't change very much).  Either way, you definitely don't need redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend against using React for your situation because there would be no difference at all.

React, and SPA's(Single Page Applications) in general, excel in scenario's where a page might constantly need to be refreshed because of new or changing data. Since you said your content is static with no changes or API calls, this is the opposite of React's intended use.

I recommend sticking with the technologies you're currently using. If you want to revamp the website i would say to focus more on the design and it look more modern through CSS and maybe some jQuery.